# Using space in case pattern in Bash

Tags: bash

I need find solution for using space in pattern in `case`. I have this function with `case`

```
  setParam() {
    case "$1" in
          0624)
            # do something - download file from url
          ;;
          del-0624)
            # do something - delete file from local machine
            exit 0
          ;;
      # Help
          *|''|h|help)
            printHelp
            exit 0
          ;;
    esac
  }

  for PARAM in $*; do
    setParam "$PARAM"
  done
```

Paramter `"0624"` is for run function for download files from url.
Paramter `"del-0624"` is for deleting files in local machine.

**Question:** It is possible use paramter `"del 0624"`(with space)? I have problem with space in parameter in `case`.

Comment: Do you mean `del 0624` as a single parameter, i.e. passed in quotes, or as two separate parameters?

Comment: I mean only single paramter - `del 0624` . No two paramter.Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You need to use `double quotes` in `case`. Also script should be run as `./script "del 0624"`.

```
setParam() {
    case "$1" in
          "0624")
            # do something - download file from url
          ;;
          "del-0624")
            # do something - delete file from local machine
            exit 0
          ;;
          "del 0624")
            # do something - delete file from local machine
            exit 0
          ;;
      # Help
          *|''|h|help)
            printHelp
            exit 0
          ;;
    esac
  }
```

Comment: First great idea. I go test it :-). And it is possible run script as ./script.sh del 0624  ?

Comment: You'll also need to use `"$@"` in the loop instead of `$*`. And `./script.sh del 0624` would be two parameters `del` and `0624`, not one `del 0624`.

Comment: Doesn't work when using wildcards `*"User choice"*`.

Comment: Single quotes `'xy z')`also work. As well as a single quoted string that end with a wildcard like `'/sbin/syslogd -s'*)`. BusyBox v1.24.2

Comment: Note that case's pattern matching is exactly the same as anywhere else.
So, if you want both spaces and wildcards in your pattern, you can either escape them: `one\ two\ *` or else use single (or double) quotes and the wildcards outside the quotes: `'one two '*`.

Answer (score 1):

This is to amend @Arjun's answer:

If you want to match spaces and wildcards in the same branch, simply escape the space by prepending a `\`.

---

`test.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case "$1" in
    foo\ *)
        echo "matched!" ;;
    *)
        echo "not matched!" ;;
esac
```

```bash
$ ./test.sh "foo bar"
matched!
$ ./test.sh "foobar"
not matched!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom **IFS** instead of the default space delimiter, in order to parse parameters that include spaces.

For example, this will replace the space before the `-` of all the script parameters with a `TAB`, and then grab the parameter name and value:

```
# Get script parameters, and split by tabs instead of space (for IFS)
SCRIPT_PARAMS="$*"
SCRIPT_PARAMS=${SCRIPT_PARAMS// -/$'\t'-}
IFS=$'\t'

for param in ${SCRIPT_PARAMS} ; do
  # Get the next parameter (flag) name, without the value
  param_name=${param%% *} 
  # Get the parameter value after the flag, without surrounding quotes
  param_value=$(echo "${param#*"$param_name" }" | xargs)
  
  case $param_name in
  -b|--basic)
    echo "Parse a basic parameter '${param_name}' without a value"
    shift ;; # After a basic parameter shift just once
  -c|--custom)
    echo "Parse a custom parameter '${param_name}' with value of: ${param_value}"
    shift 2 ;; # After a custom parameter shift twice
  -*)
    echo "Error - unrecognized parameter: ${param}" 1>&2
    exit 1 ;;
  *)
    break ;;
  esac
done

# Reset IFS
unset IFS
```